# HttpRequestException when doing a client.SendAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

All of a sudden, this piece of code that usually works started throwing  HttpRequestException errors. In the logs, I see that the request was actually sent 1 minute and 35 seconds before the error was thrown. Could it be a timeout issue?

Here is the code:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{            
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);              
    return response;           
}
```

Here is the caller (there could between 10K to 50K items):

```
int counter = 0;
var tasks = items.Select(async i =>
{
    if (await RunRequest(CreateRequest(i)))
        counter++
}).ToList();

if (tasks.Any())
{ 
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        at MyClass.<RunRequest>d__c.MoveNext()
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at MyClass.<RunRequest>d__c.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        at MyClass.<RunRequest>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Is there a limit that Task.WhenAll can handle?

Comment: "All of a sudden..." So, what changed?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of. In fact this code works well most of the time. This error come up randomly. The one possible change/variable could be the number of requests being made. There could have been about 10000 calls to RunRequest.

Comment: How long does each request usually take?

Comment: Usually just a few seconds, but in this case I noticed that the error came 2 minutes after. Is there a max number of requests that can be made at a time? I do have a throttling mechanism that allows only a certain # of requests at a given time, but I can't really control how many responses come back at the same time, so could that be the issue?

Comment: Does your server limit you to the amount of requests that can be processed concurrently?

Comment: Are you calling wait or result on some task somewhere? This could be a spurious deadlock resulting in a timeout somehow.

Comment: @usr I don't have a wait, but I have updated my post with the calling code, perhaps that could throw some light? When this error was thrown, there were 10K+ items, so that many tasks.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't think so, but I'll have to double check.

Comment: "the error came 2 minutes after": are you sure it isn't actually 1 minute and 40 seconds? the default timeout is 100 seconds

Comment: @ThomasLevesque actually, you're right, it was exactly 1 minute and 35 seconds.

Comment: 10000 is a **lot** of requests to throw at a server all at once. You might want to stagger those a bit. There's no limit to `WhenAll`; this is almost definitely a server scalability issue (not in your code). I.e., if the server is not `async`, it can't respond as quickly to sudden changes in request volume.

Answer (score 0):

If all your requests are to the same domain, then you need to add this to your "Web.config" file (default is just 2):

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
        </connectionManagement>
    <system.net>
<configuration>
```

And you are already awaiting on every single `RunRequest` in turn, serially, so nothing is actually run in paralell - and your `Task.WhenAll` should throw an exception since you are givin it a `HttpResponseMessage` list instead of a `Task` list.

`RunRequest` does not return a `bool`, so how are you using it in an `if`?

...there is just so much wrong with this code...

Comment: @Prabhu - then you are not awaiting on `RunRequest`, which is good, but the pseudo code you posted wouldn't even compile, let alone run... post the real thing