# How to perform a Depth First Search iteratively using async/parallel processing?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, task-parallel-library, async-await

Here is a method that does a DFS search and returns a list of all items given a top level item id.  How could I modify this to take advantage of parallel processing? Currently, the call to get the sub items is made one by one for each item in the stack.  It would be nice if I could get the sub items for multiple items in the stack at the same time, and populate my return list faster.  How could I do this (either using async/await or TPL, or anything else) in a thread safe manner?

```
private async Task<IList<Item>> GetItemsAsync(string topItemId)
{
    var items = new List<Item>();   
    var topItem = await GetItemAsync(topItemId);

    Stack<Item> stack = new Stack<Item>();           
    stack.Push(topItem);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = stack.Pop();
        items.Add(item);                   

        var subItems = await GetSubItemsAsync(item.SubId);

        foreach (var subItem in subItems)
        {
            stack.Push(subItem);
        }
    }

    return items;   
}
```

EDIT:
I was thinking of something along these lines, but it's not coming together:

```
var tasks = stack.Select(async item =>
{
    items.Add(item);           
    var subItems = await GetSubItemsAsync(item.SubId);

    foreach (var subItem in subItems)
    {
        stack.Push(subItem);
    }   
}).ToList();

if (tasks.Any())
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

UPDATE:
If I wanted to batch up the tasks, would something like this work?

```
foreach (var batch in items.BatchesOf(100))
{
    var tasks = batch.Select(async item =>
    {
        await DoSomething(item);
    }).ToList();

    if (tasks.Any())
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

The language I'm using is C#.

Comment: Show us the code for `GetSubItemsAsync`. What is it doing? is it IO or CPU bound work?

Comment: It's IO, a REST API call.

Comment: Is it possible to pop all items at once from the `Stack`? Will it be generating more items while you process them?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I just need a final list of ALL items under the root id specified. This method will just return the final list and won't be doing any other processing, so I think it should be okay to pop multiple items from the stack.

Comment: Thinking about it, why are you using a `Stack` at all? you already have the items once you get them from `GetItemAsync`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because it's a tree with a depth greater than one.

Comment: I'd just like to take a second to point out that if you are performing your tree traversal in parallel then it is not, by definition, going to be depth first.  The concept of a traversal being depth first, breadth first, best first, etc. is inherently dependent on it being synchronous. When traversing in parallel one will, by necessity, need to process items out of that fixed order.  You could re-order the items into the same order they would have been in had you done say a depth first, best first, etc. after actually computing them in another order, but you've said you don't want that anyway.

Comment: @Servy Figured that, and order isn't important to me in this case. I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: @Servy I just came across this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5661 it's pretty similar to what I need right? If so do you think you could help to tune it to my scenario? I tried it, but because I am using Async/Await, the return type of Task was causing issues with that approach. Any help greatly appreciated. Having both the recursive and a non-recursive approach in hand would be great.

Comment: @Prabhu Yes, [I'm quite familiar with the idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1159478+Traverse).  It simply doesn't lend itself all that well to asynchronous parallelization.  It's *possible*, sure, just the frameworks that you'd need to put in place to allow for it aren't trivial.

Comment: @Servy the main reason I was concerned about limiting the parallelization was because I started to get HttpRequestExceptions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213414/httprequestexception-when-doing-a-client-sendasync

Comment: @Prabhu Then you may be in the rare situation where you really do need to artificially limit the parallelization in one of the ways that I showed you how.

Comment: @Servy For another task based function, I put the Task.WhenAll into a forloop (see updated question). Would something like that work as a 3rd option in this scenario?

Comment: @Prabhu The main drawback I see there is that you appear to be forcing an entire level of the tree to finish before any work can be done on the level below it.  That basically means taking the time to fill and then empty your pipeline of workers at ever depth of the tree, not just at the beginning and end of the entire application.  It's also going to be inherently more work to code and I don't see any compelling benefit to that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that you can use to traverse a tree, asynchronously, and in parallel:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> TraverseAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> childSelector)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    Func<T, Task> foo = null;
    foo = async next =>
    {
        results.Add(next);
        var children = await childSelector(next);
        await Task.WhenAll(children.Select(child => foo(child)));
    };
    await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(child => foo(child)));
    return results;
}
```

The method requires a method to get the children for each node asynchronously, which you already have.  It doesn't special case generating the root node(s), so you'd want to use the method you have to get them outside of the scope of this method and provide them as this method's first argument.

The calling code may look something like this:

```
var allNodes = await new[]{await GetItemAsync(topItemId)}
    .TraverseAsync(item => GetSubItemsAsync(item.SubId));
```

The method fetches the children of each node in parallel, asynchronously, marking itself as complete when they have all finished.  Each node then recursively calculates all of *its* children in parallel.

You've mentioned that you're concerned about using recursion because of the stack space that it would consume, but that's not an issue here, because the methods are asynchronous.  Every time you move one level deep in the recursion the method isn't going on level deeper on the stack; instead it's merely scheduling the recursive method calls to be run at a later point in time, so each level always start at a fixed point on the stack.

---

If you're looking for a way of limiting the amount of parallelism, for fear that there will be just too much, I'd first ask you to try it out.  If you're directing all of the calls here to the thread pool then the thread pool itself is likely to have an upper bound on the amount of parallelism based on what it feels is likely to perform best.  It'll just stop creating more threads and just keep the pending items in a queue after a certain point, and the thread pool is far more likely to have an effective algorithm for determining the appropriate degree of parallelism than you are.  That said, if you have a compelling need to artificially limit the amount of parallelism beyond what the thread pool does, there are certainly ways.  One option is to create your own synchronization context that artificially inhibits the number of pending operations to some fixed number:

```
public class FixedDegreeSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public FixedDegreeSynchronizationContext(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreeOfParallelism,
            maxDegreeOfParallelism);
    }
    public override async void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            base.Send(d, state);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        semaphore.Wait();
        try
        {
            base.Send(d, state);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

You can create an instance of a context such as this and set it as the current context before calling `TraverseAsync` or create another overload that accepts a `maxDegreesOfParallelism` and sets the context inside the method.

Another variation of this would be to limit the number of calls to say your child selector without putting any limitations on the number of any of the other asynchronous operations that are going on here.  (None of the others should *particularly* expensive, so I wouldn't expect it to matter much either way, but this is certainly something worth experimenting with.)  To do this we could create a task queue that process the items given to it with a fixed degree of parallelism, but that won't artificially limit anything not passed to this queue.  The queue itself is simple enough, as a straightforward variation of the sync context:

```
public class FixedParallelismQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public FixedParallelismQueue(int maxDegreesOfParallelism)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreesOfParallelism,
            maxDegreesOfParallelism);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when calling the method, you can use this queue as a part of your child selector:

```
ar taskQueue = new FixedParallelismQueue(degreesOfParallelism);
var allNodes = await new[]{await GetItemAsync(topItemId)}
    .TraverseAsync(item => 
        taskQueue.Enqueue(() => GetSubItemsAsync(item.SubId)));
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on your first paragraph. Would you mind jotting down a sample calling code? Also, I might have thousands of sub items, so should I do the Task.WhenAll call in chunks?

Comment: Also, just curious, so a parallel solution wouldn't be possible using an iterative approach, or is that just not preferred for some reason?

Comment: @Prabhu I'm sure an iterative approach is *possible*.  I tried for a while and all of the iterative solutions I had come up with hadn't turned out all that well; those that seemed promising were, while incomplete, already quite a lot more complex than this.  I've edited in a sample call of the method into the post.

Comment: Thanks. So with this calling code, allNodes should have everything including itself given a topItemId, right?

Comment: @Prabhu See the next edit for a response to your concerns about excessive parallelization.

Comment: your solution works well.  I noticed though that even though I am able to make requests asynchronously (about 500 requests a second), the responses I receive back from the 3rd party API are only about 3-4 requests a second. So it turns out that my program ultimately cannot process more than 3-4 requests a second. Wondering how others have dealt with this scenario. Is there a way that my program can continue to make requests, and a separate bunch of threads take care of the responses? That way at least I can make out all the requests, and then take care of the responses as they come in.

Comment: @Prabhu You can't due to the inherent nature of your problem.  You need to receive the response for a given object before you're able to make requests for all of those children.  Your program is already making as many requests as it has the ability to do so; the bottleneck is clearly (as expected) the network interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing async and Tasks?  It seems like one or the other would be sufficient.

```
private void MainFunction(int id)
{
  var main = await GetItemAsync(id);
  await PopulateChildren(main);
}

private async void PopulateChildren(Item parent)
{
  var children = GetChildren(Item parent);
  foreach(var child in children) 
  { 
    parent.ChildCollection.Add(child); 
    PopulateChildren(child); 
  }
}

private IEnumerable<Item> GetChildren(Item parent)
{
  // I/O code
}
```

If each item doesn't hold onto its children, then you would just want to save them in a different collection instead of the parent.ChildCollection, but the code should be the same.  This isn't necessarily depth-first, but I'm not sure that was a requirement, since doing parallel you can't guarantee a particular order.

---

Ok, let's try this for something without recursion... gonna be in pseudocode, though.

```
ConcurrentBag allItems;
ConcurrentBag itemsToProcess = new ConcurrentBag(initial);

// As long as it has an item...
while(itemsToProcess.TryPeek())
{
  var tasksCurrentlyProcessing;
  // Process all the items
  while(itemsToProcess.TryTake())
  {
    tasksCurrentlyProcessing = item.GetChildren();
  }
  Task.WaitAll(tasksCurrentlyProcessing);
}

public void Task GetChildren()
{
  // get children, add to allItems and itemsToProcess
}
```

This is specifically a BFS instead of DFS.  Not sure if that works for you.  Only way I can think of to do it without recursion and without making it very complicated.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is a recursive solution. I am specifically looking for a non-recursive solution.

Comment: Any particular reason?  Any other requirements?

Comment: How deep is your tree?

Comment: That's unknown, and growing.